# Get month in date from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How can I get the month and year of the results of post data from database?

This data i want to retrieve from database is  `2016-03-11`

My code inside the controller:

```
public function report(){
    $nomor = $this->input->post('nomor_reseller');
    $bulan = $this->input->post('month'); //with format YYYY-MM

    $report_data = $this->hasil_m->get($nomor,$bulan);
    }
```

My code in model:

```
function get($nomor,$bulan) {
    $this->db->where('nomor_reseller',);
    $this->db->where('tgl_pembelian',);     
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tb_pelanggan');
    $this->db->join('tb_anggota', 'tb_anggota.id_koperasi = tb_pelanggan.id_koperasi');
    $this->db->order_by("tgl_pembelian","DESC");
    $this->db->group_by('nomor_reseller');      
    $query = $this->db->get ();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What i want to do is get `2016-03`, using $this->db->where.

Comment: please post your code here....without code how anyone understand what you need ....

Comment: thanks @DhavalPatel , I already update my question

Comment: Edited code sample

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
echo date('Y-m', strtotime($date));
```